# How to update fields in angularjs ng-cells

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using https://github.com/gdepourtales/ng-cells to display a grid of data.

In my controller I say

```
$scope.data = ... // <-- my data is in there
```

and when I display the whole thing it's just fine.
Now I update some fields in data, like

```
$scope.data[3][5]['cows'] = 26;
```

My problem: This update won't work with the ng-cells. (But is correctly displayed, if I do something like

```
{{data[3][5]['cows']}}
```

in the template.

How can i get the ng-cells grid to update correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but anyway. Your issue issue comes from the fact that angularjs does not trigger a change event when the content of an array is modified. An easy way to overcome this limitation is to make the reference to the array change like this after your update:

```
$scope.data[3][5]['cows'] = 26;    
$scope.data = $scope.data.slice();
```